# Laravel Validation and Vue 2

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have migrated from Vue 1 to Vue 2 and am having a few weird issues, the first being validation messages are displaying like this: *["Error message"]*

When using Vue 1 they would just be: *Error Message.*

This is how error messages were set using Vue 1:
    `this.$set('validation', response.data);`

and I am now doing it like so for Vue 2:
    `this.validation = response.body;`

I am displaying the error message in the html template like this:
   `{{ validation['field'] }}`

Nothing has changed from the Laravel end.

Any help would be appreciated to get these display correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it returns an array for every field because field may have more then one message , if it's one message in your case or you want to get the first message you may access it like that :

```
@{{ errors['field'] ? errors['field'][0] : null  }}
```

also use `this.validation = response.data;`

Comment: Thanks! Worked a treat. Doesn't seem to be any difference between using response.data or response.body though...